# Sequelize Express multiple models

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I can't seem to figure out how to include multiple models.

I have three models.
`Tabs, Servers, and Points`

`Tabs hasMany Server`
`Servers belongsTo Tabs and hasMany Points`
`Points belongTo Server`

In my routes I am doing this:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    models.TabConfig.findAll({
      include: [models.ServerConfig]
    }).then(function (tabs) {
      res.render('index', {
        tabs: tabs,
      });
   });
});

module.exports = router;
```

which gets me all the tabs, and the servers associated with them.  Works great.

But I want the points associated with the Servers as well so I can iterate over the tabs, servers, and points.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: on `models.TabConfig` you refer to your `Tabs` model?

Comment: Yeah sorry.  TabConfig has the Tabs model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, you can use eager loading with multiple models:

```
models.TabConfig.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: models.ServerConfig,
        include: [models.Points]
    }]
})
```

That should give you an array with all the Tabs and its Servers, and inside each Server you will have its points associated to it.

```
[{
    some: 'tab',
    saved: 'property',
    Servers: [{
        some: 'server',
        saved: 'property',
        Points: [...]
    }, ...]
}, ...]
```